# Fetch request throwing "Network Request Failed" for iOS

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-ios

I am getting a network request failed only for iOS. Android seems fine.

**Environment:**

```
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
Node: 9.4.0
Yarn: 1.3.2
npm: 5.6.0
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003
```

**Packages:**

```
react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
react-native: 0.55.1 => 0.55.1
```

**Error Message:**

> Network Request Failed

Please help me, not sure what is the issue. I have tried to update the NSAppTransportSecurity on Info.plist. Nothing worked. Any help would be apprecieated.

Comment: Are you trying on ios simulator?

Comment: Both, real device and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Allow Arbitrary Loads YES** in App Transport Security Settings in **Info.plist** file of your project

Comment: I have tried that but didnt work. 
So, in my case, the issue was with the backend. It was related to IPV6.